# How to implement own DBContext and still use the given ApplicationUser with Authentication in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I create a new Project with authentication:

[image]
Now i got this ApplicationDBContext in startup which is fine.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }
```

I saw in some tutorials that they create their own DbContext for specific usage and add it into startup. but if i want to use the ApplicationUser and my own Database tables how do i handle this dependencies?

I can't figure out what i should do here:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I know that IdentityUser has inherits DbContext, but where do i set my tables and still have User implementation?

i thought something like this but i really don't know how i should to that correctly?

[image]

Comment: What you want exactly? It's little not clearly. If you want to  use `Identity` your ApplicationDbContext need inherit `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. In `ConfigureServices` you register context , adding and configure identity system.DbContext is an important part of Entity Framework. It is a bridge between your domain or entity classes and the database.

Comment: What i want is to get one dbcontext which can handle all possible tables and not only IdentityDbContext. And i want to have it in 1 DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ApplicationDbContext` should include entity set (`DbSet<TEntity>`)  for all the entities which is mapped to database tables.  `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` represents a class which uses a custom user entity with a string primary key.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` should inherit `IdentityUser` class. Your model should look like:

```
public  class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

[Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx)  you find much more about `DbContext` and what you can to do with

> DbContext is the primary class that is responsible for interacting with data as object. DbContext is responsible for the following
>   activities:
>
> - **EntitySet**: DbContext contains entity set (DbSet) for all the
>     entities which is mapped to DB tables.
> - **Querying**: DbContext converts
>     LINQ-to-Entities queries to SQL query and send it to the database.
> - **Change Tracking**: It keeps track of changes that occurred in the
>     entities after it has been querying from the database.
> - **Persisting Data**: It also performs the Insert, Update and Delete operations to the
>     database, based on what the entity states.
> - **Caching**: DbContext does first level caching by default. It stores the entities which have been
>     retrieved during the life time of a context class.
> - **Manage
>     Relationship**: DbContext also manages relationship using CSDL, MSL and
>     SSDL in DB-First or Model-First approach or using fluent API in
>     Code-First approach. Object Materialization: DbContext converts raw
>     table data into entity objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your models like I added

```
DbSet<Table> Tables {get; set;}
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

      DbSet<Table> Tables {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```